# Using a template callback function in C++

Tags: c++, templates, callback, c2664

I want to have a function that checks certain conditions based on a given callback function.

Considers this code:

```
class Foo{
template <class ParamType>
struct IsGood
{
    typedef bool (*Check)(typename const ParamType*, int other);
};
template< typename ParamType >
void DoSmth(IsGood<ParamType>::Check isGood, const ParamType* param){
   //...
   if(isGood(param, some_int_calculated_here)) doSmthElse();
}
```

What I want is to call it with:

```
bool checkEqualInt(int* i, int j){return *i==j;}
bool checkEqualFloat(float* i, float j){return *i==j;}

DoSmth(checkEqualInt, &i);
DoSmth(checkEqualFloat, &i_float);
```

(All constructed examples to show the problem)

The compiler won't get that and throws me error C2664 "converting param 1 from bool(int*,int) in bool(ParamType,int) not possible"

I there a solution without using

```
template< typename ParamType, Check >
void DoSmth(Check isGood, const ParamType param)
```

Which ommits the necessary declaration of the check function?

Best solution would be to get the IsGood() header in the function itself.

Comment: I didn't see that last line before answering. Why is it that using a template parameter that represents a functor is not an option?

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/czNr1e (after adding/removing `typename` where necessary).

Comment: @user2093113 `checkEqualFloat` won't work though.

Comment: @mfontanini Indeed, but that is because `checkEqualFloat` as specified in the question doesn't match the `IsGood<float>::Check` function signature. Correcting the signature to take an `int` as the second parameter works: http://ideone.com/vx6ao8.

Comment: @user2093113: Your code is working. I just forgot something: The ParamTypes are given as pointers.
I updated the question. Sorry for that. I thought it got to be the same.
It works However with ommitting pointers in IsGood and use "DoSmth(IsGood<ParamType*>::Check"
But it looks strange

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the first argument of your template function is not deducible:

```
template< typename ParamType >
void DoSmth(typename IsGood<ParamType>::Check isGood, const ParamType param)
//          ^        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//          missing  nested type! not deducible!
```

The simple option is to expand the signature in place (C++03,C++11):

```
template< typename ParamType >
void DoSmth(void (*isGood)(ParamType,int), const ParamType param)
// note: dropped 'const' that will be dropped anyway by the compiler
```

Or if you have C++11 you can substitute the `IsGood<ParamType>::Check` by a template alias:

```
template <typename T>
using IsGood = void (*)(T,int);
template< typename ParamType >
void DoSmth(IsGood<ParamType> isGood, const ParamType param)
```

Or alternatively refactor your code to take a functor that will make it more flexible, simple and possibly efficient since there will be easier for the compiler to inline the call:

```
template <typename P, typename T>
void DoSmth(P predicate, T param) {
   if (predicate(param,somethingelse)) { ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a functor template will solve your issues:

```
template< typename Functor, typename ParamType >
void DoSmth(Functor isGood, const ParamType param){
   //...
   if(isGood(param, some_int_calculated_here)) doSmthElse();
}
```

Now you can use any function or functor object that has a compatible signature(not necessarily one that takes a `ParamType` and an `int` as parameters).  Otherwise, you'll need to use functions with that exact signature.

Comment: As mentioned, I wanted to avoid the functor to specify the function signature in the function header itself